# Problem with WebExtensions: second injected script doesn't see the first one

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, firefox-addon-webextensions

I need to create Firefox WebExtension that should use Amazon AWS SDK for Javascript. So to use its functions I try to inject such scripts into the loaded page:

```html
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.485.0.min.js"></script>
<script>My code using AWS functions</script>
```

When I just create such page it works fine:

```html
<html>
<body>
<script src="https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.485.0.min.js">
<script">console.log(AWS)</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Then I try to inject this code to the loaded page with WebExtensions content script like:

```js
var s1 = document.createElement('script');
s1.src = "https://sdk.amazonaws.com/js/aws-sdk-2.485.0.min.js";
document.body.appendChild(s1);

var s2 = document.createElement('script');
s2.textContent = "console.log(AWS);";
document.body.appendChild(s2);
```

The scripts are successfully injected but in this case the second script returns the error: "AWS is not defined".

How can I fix this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to wait for the remote script to load because it takes time. Put the s2 block inside s1.onload = function () { ....... }

Comment: Great, that's what I needed, thank you!